# Vegetable suet without the palm oil, or an equivalent?

Tags: substitutions, fat, vegetarian

I use [Atora vegetable suet](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/product/speciality-ingredients/atora-vegetable-shredded-suet-240g)* to make Christmas pudding. I might be giving it to vegetarians, at least in a normal year, and I'd rather avoid unnecessary meat products myself. With the leftover suet this year I've made some rather good individual suet puddings**, and I think I might want to make more in the future.  But I noticed that vegetable suet is mainly palm oil, which I'd avoid if I could on environmental grounds.  [Trex](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/product/cooking-and-baking-butters-and-spreads/trex-vegetable-fat-250g) solid vegetable fat is also mainly palm oil; this is (I think) what Americans would call "vegetable shortening".

So is there an equivalent to suet, for use in Christmas pudding and/or suet pastry, that isn't based on palm oil?

---

* <sub>I see Tesco do an own brand - that also has palm oil first, followed by rice flour then sunflower oil.  It's lower fat in total but roughly calculating the saturated fat it contains about the same amount of palm oil.</sub>

** <sub>Caramelised onion, mushroom, and chestnut was one recipe, leek and strong cheese the other.  They're very easy in a slow cooker.</sub>

Comment: Can't see one even in the organics. Some just claim such as "Non-hydrogenated vegetable oil (90%) from sustainable sources, sunflower seed oil (10%) and white rice flour." without declaring which oil. It might be a which can you make into a solid at room temperature thing - veg ghee is also palm oil. See http://www.veganbaking.net/articles/tools/fat-and-oil-melt-point-temperatures

Comment: @Tetsujin similar googling suggests [Suma organic](https://www.naturalcollection.com/shop/suma-gluten-free-vegetarian-suet---250g-by-suma-wholefoods/?PCode=DSGPESS15) is "sustainable" (which is often questionable, but I won't go into that here) palm oil. https://www.buywholefoodsonline.co.uk/vegan-suet-500g.html states the certification of their palm oil, which is progress